# Moving from 1 Linux Partition to Many over USB Mount

Tags: debian, partitioning

We have devices which use Compact Flash for storage. They work OK, but we recently got industrial-grade CF cards to start using.

One of the major problems we get is corruption on the flash card. As it is now, these flash cards run Debian with everything in a single partition. We want to have multiple partitions on the new industrial CF cards to help avoid some of the corruption problems.

I booted up the device, and attached a USB CF reader. I then used fdisk to partition the CF card in the USB reader.

How can I move the data to these partitions so that it works? I have a partition for each of these directories:

- /lib
- /var
- /root
- /boot
- /tmp
- /home
- /etc
- /
- swap space

I imagine I can't just use rsync - do I need to attach a second CF reader with a copy of the CF card, so that it's not active and in-use - and then copy from the first reader to the second? How will the system know where to find its files?

I know I'd have to change fstab, but that resides in /etc, which will be on a separate partition...how will it find the fstab file if it can't find /etc? And what about grub?

I'm at a loss, perhaps its just because I'm under the weather, or I'm just missing a piece of logic here...

Any help is greatly appreciated, this is somewhat urgent as our existing stock is nearing its end and we don't want to purchase anything but these industrial cards, but need to get it working with partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move `/lib` or `/etc` out of the root partition. You might be able to move selected pieces off, but generally speaking, programs that are kept out of `/usr` and their dependencies (such as libraries in `/lib` and configuration files in `/etc`) are the ones that tend to be necessary early in the system boot, before `/usr` can be mounted.

For `/root`, `/var`, `/home`, `/usr` and `/boot`, you can just move the data to the new partition with `mv`, then add the proper entry to `/etc/fstab`. I recommend doing that from a rescue system; especially for `/var`, moving files on a live system requires experience of an if-you-need-to-ask-you-don't-have-it kind.

For `/tmp`, make it live entirely in memory (that's virtual memory, so in a sense its storage backend is the swap space, if this becomes necessary due to lack of RAM). Add the following line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs mode=1777
```

---

I wonder if you're really going in the right direction. I just don't see how making multiple partitions could help avoid corruption. Maybe what you need is some form of RAID (this requires that the devices have multiple CF readers, unless you're willing to sacrifice a lot of performance and disk space for a chance of detecting corruption), or a filesystem with some corruption detection (something which Linux doesn't support well — I think your best bet is [btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs)).

Comment: I'll give it a go leaving /lib and /etc in the root partition. I attached a second CF reader so I'm not copying from the filesystem I'm booted from. Fingers crossed it works :)